# PGFPlots external crossref updates

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing, external

I’m using the PGFPlots package along with its `external` library for my dissertation. Overall, it's worked great and has been extremely helpful.  But I've had issues when trying to update cross-references to plot shapes.  I've made a minimum working example of a plot generated using PGFPlots with a cross-reference in the main text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\pgfkeys{
    /tikz/external/mode=list and make
}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=black] coordinates {
    (0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1,1) };
\label{plot:plot1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Plot 1 looks like this:~\ref{plot:plot1}.

\end{document}
```

The standard process to create this is two iterations of the following:

1. Run this with `pdflatex`.
2. Run `make` using a Unix client like Cygwin with the `\jobname.makefile` that's generated from step 1.

However, if you then change the display of the plot from `black` to `blue`, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\pgfkeys{
    /tikz/external/mode=list and make
}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=newest}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[color=blue] coordinates {
    (0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1,1) };
\label{plot:plot1}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Plot 1 looks like this:~\ref{plot:plot1}.

\end{document}
```

and run the same process, the cross-reference doesn't update.  I can force it to update by first deleting the cross reference files starting with `\jobname-figure_crossref0,` but I was hoping there's a way to automatically update them each time I update the figures.

I'd prefer this to work with a document containing many more figures placed in multiple folders by way of a commands similar to `\tikzsetnextfilename{myFolder/myPlotName}` before each `\tikzpicture`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up, while quite detailed, is unfortunately not easy to follow. Please post a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that shows what exactly you're looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if this is a bug or not, but to find out I added it to the tracker [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/118/).

In the meantime you can work around this problem by not externalizing the `\ref`s, which I would suggest anyway, because they "do not cost compilation time". You can avoid the externalization by adding `\tikzset{/tikz/external/export next=false}` in front of the `\ref` command.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        external,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        width=7cm,
        compat=newest,
    }
    \tikzexternalize[
%        mode=list and make,
    ]
    % command to switch on/off the externalization of the next picture
    \newcommand*{\TE}{%
        \tikzset{
            /tikz/external/export next=false,
        }%
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
                (0,0) (0.5,0.5) (1,1)
            };
            \label{plot:plot1}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    Plot~1 looks like this:~\TE\ref{plot:plot1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It was a bit cumbersome changing up all of these commands in my dissertation, but once that was done, everything's worked great!  Is this workaround compatible with the tikzexternal package?

Comment: @MikeyHannon, you are welcome. I don't think that this will work with the `tikzexternal` package, because this assumes that _all_ pictures are externalized. But why should you need to switch to the `tikzexternal` package with your dissertation?

Comment: @MikeyHannon, if you really should need to switch to the `tikzexternal` package I suggest to create a command for `\tikzset{/tikz/external/export next=false}` and at the really end, when nothing in the pictures will change any more, you can just change the definition of the command and then externalize the `\ref`s. See my edited anser.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!  I don't need it for my dissertation, but I wanted to know in case it became necessary for submitting a manuscript to a journal that didn't allow the tikz package, which has happened to me before.

Comment: @MikeyHannon, you don't need it necessarily, but then you must also give them the "data files" which in most cases is not what you want. So for these cases I also would recommend using the `tikzexternal` package.

Comment: I have to come back to this old post because I have the same problem.
Your suggested solution seems to work fine, however, it introduces too extra space before the reference. How can this be suppressed?

Comment: @smarties, they originated from the `\TE` command. See my edited answer, where I added some comment signs to avoid them.